# Need assistance understanding this part of Obj-c delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

In [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) says:

> **Locating Objects Through the delegate Property** The existence of delegates has other programmatic uses. For example, with delegates it
>   is easy for two coordinating controllers in the same program to find
>   and communicate with each other. For example, the object controlling
>   the application overall can find the controller of the application’s
>   inspector window (assuming it’s the current key window) using code
>   similar to the following:
>
> id winController = [[NSApp keyWindow] delegate]; And your code can
>   find the application-controller object—by definition, the delegate of
>   the global application instance—by doing something similar to the
>   following:
>
> id appController = [NSApp delegate];

I am not clearly getting this point, please can any one explain this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think it implies that the delegate objects can be used as communication interfaces between different parts of the code and reaching them from where needed is easy.

In the example above, winController and appController have different functionalities. They do not know the inner-workings of each other. The delegate interface provides a way for them to communicate. Also, it helps that accessing the delagates is easy.